# Can I monitor a server (microsoft or unix) REMOTELY with prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, server-monitoring

I'm new to Prometheus and have been unable to find the answer to this.
I need to monitor the performance and services of a remote server and I'm looking into Prometheus for this purpose.

It seems easy enough to monitor a server in the same machine as Prometheus but what I need is to monitor an remote server without installing Prometheus on it.

So far I've failed to find any conclusive answers either way.

Comment: Your question is likely off-topic for Stack overflow and likely to get flagged for removal.

Comment: Prometheus is well-suited to monitoring (remote) services and systems and there's an extensive [list](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/) of integrations. The getting-started integration where Prometheus monitors itself uses a network address (often `localhost` in this case) and a port to scrape metrics from the service. This is the same principle whether the server is local or remote, regardless of port and simply requires that the "thing" publish metrics in the Prometheus (Exposition) format so that Prometheus may scrape them.

Comment: I encourage you to read Prometheus extensive [documentation](https://prometheus.io) as this will answer this type of general question better than Stack overflow. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one has to install exporters on the target servers. You can then in you .yml file you can set the target of those servers using the ip address. What I still working out is the security issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try mobaxterm.
This software help you to monitor and run scripts on your server

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).